# How to select only certain part in a match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string.

```
/v/dkdkd-akdoa?
```

I would like to replace `dkdkd-akdoa`.

My replace method looks like

```
string.replace("v\/(.+)\?", "replace")
```

but it also replaces `v/`. How do I replace only `dkdkd-akdoa`?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply

```
string.replace(/v\/.+\?/, "v/replace");
```

If the first part is not known you can capture and replace it:

```
string.replace(/(v\/).+\?/, "$1replace");
```

Obviously in the second example it is known since `v/` is constant.  You would potentially replace it with something like `/^(.*?/).+\?/`

Answer (score 5):

Try following code:

```
> '/v/dkdkd-akdoa?'.replace(/(v\/).+\?/, '$1replace')
"/v/replace"
```

If you want keep `?`:

```
> '/v/dkdkd-akdoa?'.replace(/(v\/).+(?=\?)/, '$1replace')
"/v/replace?"
```

`$1` reference the first group (`(v\/)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can break it up so the prefix and suffix are their own matching groups and include them in the replaced value:

```
string.replace(/(v\/)(.+)(\?)/, "$1replace$3");
```

Or more simply treat your pattern you're replacing as a non-matching group:

```
string.replace(/(v\/).+(\?)/, "$1replace$2")
```